# Sharepoimt Online Event Receiver - Consume Custom Web Service

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, event-receiver

Well, the title is self descriptive, but here's my issue again:

I have a SharePoint Online which I've managed attach some event receiver to one of it's list, now after this is successfully done, i need to call an external web service (WCF) from that event receiver but i can't (I get "No endpoints were found for serivce . . .")

Does anyone know how to do this.

I'm pretty new to SPO, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Best regards.

---

Edit: The solution is not Provider-hosted, it's a SharePoint App and as for the WCF service it is hosted on some public server of our's (Not SharePoint hosted)

Comment: @Andrew i saw from your question [azure - Remote event receiver authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458991/remote-event-receiver-authentication/37798438?noredirect=1#comment63063092_37798438) that you might know how could this be done, can you help please, would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

How did you manage to attach the event receiver? 
If by Provider-hosted Add-in - are you developing it locally?
Because you can use [Azure Service Bus](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/01/03/debugging-remote-event-receivers-with-visual-studio/) as an endpoint (as described) to debug the remote event receiver.

I suggest that this will help you with the WCF service too.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Sure, but I still don't have the reputation to add comments, and wanted to help the user